# Python Curve_fit.optimize put function model with condition between variables

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

i have a function like this :

[image]

i use curve_fit to fit my data.... wrote this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


db = pd.read_excel("/Users/piero/Desktop/lavori/AIF/test.xlsx")


M0=np.array(db['M0'])
t_time=np.array(db['time'])


def func(t, K, t0, a, b):
            if t > t0 :
                f = K * ((t-t0)**a) * np.exp(-(t-t0)/b)
                return f
            return 0

params_guess=[2,3,4,1]
popt,pcov= curve_fit(func,t_time,M0,p0=params_guess)
```

and i've this error

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

So i understand that in my function func i can't compare an array with a number but i need to put t>t0 condition in my fit. Does anyone know how to do?

Answer (score 1):

You want to evaluate the condition you've written here at *each element* of the array `t`. The function is called with an entire array as `t`, which may span the point `t0`. In Numpy, you can do this kind of conditional evaluation in a number of ways, but the simplest is:

```py
def func(t, K, t0, a, b):
    return np.where(t > t0, K * (t - t0) ** a * np.exp(-(t - t0) / b), 0.0)
```

This should be read as: "At array indices where the condition `t > t0` is true, return values from the first expression, and at other values return 0.0."